# The \@Latintrue command is not accepted by the polyglossia or bidi packages

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, bidi

I've updated today my miktex distribution, especially the `bidi` package (and others...) from the 19.6 version to the actually version, because of unwanted behaviour in writing the negative numbers. In the preceding version, I used `\makeatletter\@Latintrue\makeatother` command which enabled me to produce tabulars in the way I want (in RightToLeft or in LeftToRight mode)...

Now after the update, this command is not recognized and produces the error message "! Undefined control sequence. \makeatletter\@Latintrue..".

What happened and how can I fix it ?

I give the .tex file used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}%%% May choose the arabic font you want


%\makeatletter\@Latintrue\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright  %% For writing "completely" in LTR mode..

\LR{The positive numbers are ok, like for 36.3 (Unlike the version 19.6 of bidi, which wrote 3.36 ... (}

\LR{The negative numbers are not ok: for example, for -55 , where the sign is written on the right}

\LR{For the tabulars too, the behavior is bad. It's written always in RightToLeft mode, even if I put it into 
$\backslash$LR\{ \{...}

\LR{\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a&b&c\\
\hline
1&-1&-2.3\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\par}

\end{document}
```

and its compilation, using xelatex:
[image]

Comment: `bidi` has changed and `\if@Latin` has been discarded.

Comment: so what's the similar command for doing the job now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of @UlrikeFicher answer you can patch the definition of `\LR` to use the font without `Script=Arabic` feature with

```
\let\oldLR\LR
\renewcommand{\LR}[1]{\oldLR{\fontspec{Arial} #1}}
```

For negative sign on the left for numbers in RTL context  here a  workaround

```
\catcode`\-=\active
\def-{\ifmmode\char`\-\else\char`\-\char"200E \fi}
```

It remains a statement of the bug to `fontspec` or `bidi` maintainers

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\catcode`\-=\active
\def-{\ifmmode\char`\-\else\char`\-\char"200E \fi}

\let\oldLR\LR
\renewcommand{\LR}[1]{\oldLR{\fontspec{Arial} #1}}


\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedright  %% For writing "completely" in LTR mode..

\LR{The positive numbers are ok, like for 36.3 (Unlike the version 19.6 of bidi, which wrote 3.36 ... )}

\LR{The negative numbers are not ok: for example, for -55 , where the sign is written on the right}

\LR{For the tabulars too, the behavior is bad. It's written always in RightToLeft mode, even if I put it into 
$\backslash$LR\{...\}}

\begin{LTR}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a&b&c\\
\hline
1&-1&-2.3\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\par
\end{LTR}


-55  $-55$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is useful for the question about \LR. What about the question about the output of negative numbers where the sign -appears in the right of the numbers, when it's not inside \LR{ }...? his was not the case for the previous version !

Comment: Thank you for your ingenious code.  I have a last question:  for your new `\LR`, the command `\fontspec{Arial}` disturb me a little... can I choose the font that I want? If I use it for a tabular containing arabic and english words, what happens'?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer but too long for a comment. The test `\if@Latin` has been removed. There seems to be now the test `\if@nonlatin` which can be set with `\setlatin` and `\setnonlatin`, but imho it won't help with your problem and you should better analyze your problem more carefully instead of using undocumented side effects and work-arounds which can always break.

I never use bidi, don't know arabic and have no idea how numbers should be input and printed. But your negative numbers have the sign on the right side with Arial not because of bidi or polyglossia but because you are using  `Script=arabic`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
 -55 -45   
 −55 −45


 \sffamily
 -55 -45    
 −55 −45

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The numbers should be printed exactly like in the english mode. It was the case before my last update... I'm really perplexed about this update... what happen's ?

Comment: I tried the commands `\makeatletter\@nonlatintrue\makeatother` and `\makeatletter\@nonlatinfalse\makeatother`.. It's accepted but hasn't any effect

Comment: I get the wrong negative numbers with TeXLive 2015 too (and with \@Latintrue), so it is certainly not new. Perhaps you removed some relevant code while making the example.

Comment: So what about the tabulars, on which the command \LR{} has absolutely no effect ?.. in 2015 this command inverse the columns... so the last become the first, and so on !

Comment: As I said: I don't use bidi. But I get a warning from your \LR (`\endL or \endR problem (0 missing, 1 extra) `), so I would say that you are misusing the command. With `\begin{LTR}` ... `\end{LTR}` it seems to work fine.

Comment: Your commands work fine, thank you, but the command \LR worked fine too, in the last version...

Comment: May be (but not for me), but if you are using the wrong commands it is always possible that it breaks after an update. The documentation of bidi explictly says that with `\LR` "you can typeset *short* LTR text
*inside* RTL paragraphs.". So using it for something with a \par in it is bound to give problems.

Comment: ok...perhaps true... but it's absolutely the first time I see this behaviour (... inside @Latintrue of course)...